# Angular 4 : How to generate code coverage for all files and export for Sonar

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I'm implementing  Code coverage taaks for my angular app , to display its results in Sonarqube.

My **karma.conf.js** looks like this:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

my **test.ts** file looks like this :

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /app.component\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

When i run some test i execute : `ng tests --code-coverage`

1 - My first problem : In fact it shows me the result of my coverage task *for only one / few parts of my code* **and not all my files.**

**So how can i generate coverage for all my project files** ?

2 - **My second problem** is with sonarqube :

In facts it seems that results generated within karma , are not the same show in Sonar

**Example :** within **karma** it's 50%  **->** In **sonar** is shows 10%

my **sonar-project.properties** looks like this :

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=Nomadis
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=SocleRCD_FrontV2
sonar.projectVersion=2.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources=./src/app

sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.tests=./src/app
#sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts

sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=./tslint.json


# To import the LCOV report
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: you have 2 most probably unrelated questions, try to separate them and create a new question. BTW for second problem provide more details, e.g. find a concrete file where covered lines showed by karma and by sonar are different

Comment: I believe sonar computes code coverage based on your project's overall sources.Karma plugins on the other hand will only compute code coverage for the code involved in your tests. This may not include all of your project's sources (your tests may not import 100% of all production code). This can produce different % coverage.